# HTML 5 video: iPad video is black

Tags: html, ipad, video

I know, there are several answers addressing this problem, but none has worked for what I am doing. I am trying to place a video. It works fine on all my desktop browsers, but the one I really need to work it on--my iPad-- is a no go. It used to display a striked-through play button, but I managed to make that go away and now all I see on the screen is a black box. When this happened, I hoped it was a step in the right direction, but now I am not sure.

My mark-up is:

```
<video height="250" controls>
<source src="closeI.m4v"  type="video/m4v" />
<source src="graphics/close.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="graphics/graphics/close.oggtheora.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

Video is an unfamiliar realm for me, but I am doing my best. Thank you.

Comment: Could be an encoding issue. Have you tried [MiroVideoConverter](http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/)? Additionally check your encodings with [GSpot](http://www.headbands.com/gspot/). To see a working example http://www.pegasedream.be/

Comment: Another [link](http://www.creativeplanetnetwork.com/oldsvcimage/images/042010Table1-600.jpg) for you to see. iPad video should go at 720p.

Comment: I had converted with Miro. I really liked using it, but I expected a m4v file and instead got a few mp4s. Wasn't sure how they are different from each or even which one to use. So I used another program to convert my mp4 to and m4v.

Comment: At your recommendation I used GSpot, I'm not sure what I am looking for. Can't copy/paste a screen shot here. It is an m4v file, Codec avc1, Name H.264/MPEG-4AVC. The status says Codec Status Undetermined. The frame speed is different than on the table you suggested--so I'll at least go back and try changing that--but I'm going to refer to some of the answers I found earlier to try and make sense of the potential encoding issue.

Comment: I'll follow-up after I get a chance to look at this later tonight.

Comment: No problem, video encoding can be a pain to get it right. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with the `m4v` extension. I used `webm` instead, next to `mp4` and `ogv`.

Comment: It was an encoding issue. I did a little more research and a lot more reading, and I understand why things are exported the way they are more than I did before. Like I said before, video is pretty foreign to me. I'm glad I had read a bunch of other suggestions before asking the forum because what ultimately solved my problem was searching for a specific post I remembered reading earlier in the day. The terms in the articles I was reading helped me to locate it.