# Youtube video black screen in iPhone5

Tags: youtube, iphone-5

I don't have an iPhone 5, but my client has it, and he says that when tapping on a movie it goes to the Youtube movie (he can see thumbnail) but does not play the movie.  It only displays a black screen. [Here is the link](http://yalleshleiron.com/ds/companies/apple/)(just click/tap on first image to play the video). I hope you can help, I can't see the bug because I don't have an iPhone5.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19866977/ipad-video-square-black

Comment: How can it help me? I am using embedded youtube video.

Comment: I dunno, I only remembered I saw a similar question so I pointed that out. The fact that you're using an embeded video including you're markup should be added to your question.